# Текст в EditText пишется в одну линию

Tags: android, android-edittext

Здравствуйте. Экран содержит вьюхи разбитые по весу. WeightSum = 100. Вес у `EditText` = 40. Сейчас текст пишется в одну линию. А надо чтобы писался во весь блок по высоте. Знаю что есть атрибут `lines` но я же не могу их насчитать. Из-за веса на разных экранах будет разная высота. Как быть?

Comment: [может](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) поможет

Comment: Неа я уже справился)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавил

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:maxHeight="0dp"
```